# Как оставить только уникальные значения в обьекте?

Tags: javascript

Имеется обьект типа:

```
obj=[
 { t: 841, b: 845 },
    { t: 844, b: 846 },
    { t: 841, b: 845 },
    { t: 844, b: 846 }]
```

Как убрать одинаковые значения и оставить только уникальные?

```
obj=[ { t: 841, b: 845 },
    { t: 844, b: 846 }]
```

Comment: @AzizUmarov, и каким образом Set поможет с объектами?

Comment: Поторопился щя перепишу

Comment: одинаковыми должны быть все поля? или какое-то одно поле ключевое?

Answer (score 3):

Вот так попробуйте:

```js
let obj=[
 { t: 841, b: 845 },
    { t: 844, b: 846 },
    { t: 841, b: 845 },
    { t: 844, b: 846 }]

let res = obj.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
  if (accumulator.every(item => !(item.t === currentValue.t && item.b === currentValue.b)))              accumulator.push(currentValue);
  return accumulator;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 3):

Ещё один вариант)

```js
let obj = [
  { t: 841, b: 845 },
  { t: 844, b: 846 },
  { t: 841, b: 845 },
  { t: 844, b: 846 }
];

//- преобразуем каждый объект в строку
//- создаем Set(он оставит только уникальные значения)
//- создаём массив
//- каждый элемент(строку) - преобразуем в объект

let unique = Array.from(new Set(obj.map(item => JSON.stringify(item)))).map(item => JSON.parse(item));

console.log(unique)
```

Comment: Так ещё можно сократить:
`let unique = [...new Set(obj.map(item => JSON.stringify(item)))].map(item => JSON.parse(item));`

Comment: Не будет правильно работать с `obj = [ { t: 841, b: 845 },  { b: 845, t: 841 }]`

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли. Код работает.

Answer (score 2):

1. Сортируем каждый объект (элемент исходного массива) по возрастанию ключей с помощью `sort()`.
2. Преобразовываем каждый объект в JSON.
3. С помощью `Set` оставляем только уникальные значения, и затем преобразовываем в  массив.
4. Каждый элемент полученного массива преобразуем из JSON в объект.

Недостаток метода - если значениями в объектах исходного массива будут не числа, а так же массивы или объекты, то их значения должны быть предварительно отсортированы.

```js
const obj = [{
    t: 841, b: 845
  },
  {
    t: 844, b: 846
  },
  {
    t: 841, b: 845
  },
  {
    b: 846, t: 844
  }
];
let res = 
    [...new Set(
        obj.map(item => JSON.stringify(
            Object.keys(item)
                .sort()
                .reduce((obj, value) => (obj[value] = item[value], obj), {})
        ))
    )].map(item => JSON.parse(item));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Вместо filter можно Set использовать.
Написал в своём варианте

Comment: Ага, увидел, даже интересно что было бы быстрее при большом объёме.

Comment: Как и в другом ответе с `JSON.stringify`, не будет правильно работать с `obj = [ { t: 841, b: 845 },  { b: 845, t: 841 }]`

Comment: @Yaant это да. Можно добавить сортировку по ключам, но это не будет жизнеспособно для значений типа массив и объект, где тоже может быть путаница. Надо подумать.

Answer (score -1):

```js
    let unicObject = [];
    obj.forEach((item) => {
    if(!unicObject.find((unic) => unic.t === item.t || unic.b === item.b)){
       unicObject.push(item);
    }
    });
```